# error in creating a http request in vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I receive the following errors in the console when I try to create an ajax HTTP request using Vue. I am new to Vue so please help me. I am using the HTTP post to go to a route using post which in turn calls a controller store function.

the error in console log is this

```
new.vue?79f8:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at VueComponent.store (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:93), <anonymous>:48:31)
    at VueComponent.boundFn [as store] (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:86), <anonymous>:182:12)
    at VueComponent.fileInputChange (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:93), <anonymous>:43:18)
    at boundFn (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:86), <anonymous>:181:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.invoker (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:86), <anonymous>:1823:18)
```

my new.vue is this. I call the http post here

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Upload Video</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <input type="file" name="video" id="video" @change="fileInputChange" v-if="!uploading">
                        <div id="video-form" v-if="uploading && !failed">
                            form

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                uploading:false,
                uploadingComplete:false,
                failed:false,
                title:'untitled',
                description:null,
                visibility:'private',
            }
        },
        methods:{
            fileInputChange(){
                this.uploading = true;
                this.failed = false;
                this.file=document.getElementById('video').files[0];
                this.store().then(()=>{
                    //upload the video
                })
            },
            store(){
                return this.$http.post('/video', {
                    title: this.title,
                    description: this.description,
                    visibility: this.visibility,
                    extension: this.file.name.split('.').pop()
                }).then((response)=>{
                    console.log(response.json());
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {

        }
    }
</script>
```

and my app.js is

```
    //
    // /**
    //  * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
    //  * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
    //  * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
    //  */
    //
    //  require('./bootstrap');
    // window.Vue = require('vue');
    //
    // /**
    //  * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
    //  * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
    //  * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
    //  */
    //
    //  Vue.component('video-upload', require('./components/new.vue'));
    //
    // const app = new Vue({
    //     el: '#app',
    // });

    import Vue from 'vue'
    import New from './components/new.vue'
    import VueResource from 'vue-resource'



   // Vue.component('video-upload', require('./components/new.vue'));

    Vue.use(VueResource);

    new Vue({
        render(h) {
            return h(New)
        }
    }).$mount('#video-upload')
```

Comment: Are you using [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource)? There is no `$http` member in ordinary Vue.

Comment: yes i am using vue-resource

Comment: The error is telling you that `$http` is undefined. I don't see any reason `this` shouldn't be correct, but that's where to look next.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the route as parameter so you can reuse the same function, and the input should also be a parameter, you are trying to post (nothing)

```
store(route, input) {
            if(input != '') {
                this.$http.post(route, input)
                .then(resp => {
                    this.post = []; // empty your session post object

          window.setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 
  resp.body.redirect },5); // redirect
                })
            }
        },
```